# Can't extract links out of xml content

Tags: xml, vba, excel, web-scraping

I've wrtten a script in vba to get all the links within different nodes out of a sitemap link but can't make a go successfully.

How can I fetch those links?

This is what I've tried already:

```
Sub TestXML()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Xmldoc As Object
    Dim post As Object, R&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.klerenmakendebaby.nl/product-sitemap.xml", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set Xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        Xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.xml
    End With

    For Each post In Xmldoc.SelectNodes("//url")
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.SelectNodes(".//loc")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Upon execution It fetches nothing, not throws any error either.

Answer (score 1):

As per the following? Add a reference to Microsoft XML Library for your version. I am on Excel 2016 so using xml 6.0. and document60.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestXML()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, R&, aNodeList As Object, bNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.klerenmakendebaby.nl/product-sitemap.xml", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" 
        .send
        Xmldoc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With
    Set aNodeList = Xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//loc")
    For Each bNode In aNodeList.Context.ChildNodes
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = bNode.FirstChild.Text
    Next bNode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not that it matters or breaks the code, but both of your `Application.ScreenUpdating` assignments are `True`. Probably just a bad paste.

Comment: oops...sorry twas paste indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the same is like:

```
Sub TestXML()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim Xdoc As New DOMDocument, post As Object, R&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.klerenmakendebaby.nl/product-sitemap.xml", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Xdoc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Xdoc.getElementsByTagName("url")
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByTagName("loc")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Comment: if you see an accidental edit I apologise. The damn swopping of ordering of answers meant I edited your question noy mine. Sorry.